# SQL Update across Two different Tables in Microsoft Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im new kind of new to SQL and im trying to get an update query across Two Tables. Specificly i got those two tables:

```
PERSON (name, surname, email, phone, adress_id, room_id)
```

and

```
ROOM (room_id, number_of_beds, house_id)
```

and i would like to update the person on room_id. I thought of a statement like:

```
UPDATE PERSON
SET room_id = room_id
FROM ROOM
INNER JOIN ROOM ON 
    room_id = room_id
```

My friend told me to use aliases for a better overview but i don't understand how to use those.

Would this statement work and how could i use aliases in the statement?

Comment: As your tables are defined, a person knows which room (singular) they have, not the other way around. If a person is moving to another room you would use `update Person set Room_Id = @New_Room_Id where Person_Id = @Person_Id`. Sadly, you don't seem to have a way to uniquely identify a person, so that makes it all a little vague. (Just ask eBay about email addresses being unique and permanent identifiers for users.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update p--is an alias to person
set 
p.stuffyouwantset=r.stuffyouwant
from 
person p
join
room r
on p.room_id=r.room_id
```